# Combine data sets in SSIS based on columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a data set which is of following format in excel

```
Col A Col B WW1 WW2 WW3.... WW51 Ww52
```

The columns A & B has text values and `WW1` to `WW52` has numeric values. This data is unpivoted to the following format into a SQL staging table

```
Col A Col B CurrentWW WorkWeeks Qty
```

The WorkWeeks column will have 52 workweek values including the current work week in the format `yyyyww` and `Qty` as numeric. A sample data set will look like as follows :

```
ColA ColB CurrentWW WorkWeeks Qty
US01 ABC   201717    201717    1
US01 EFG   201717    201718    1
US01 HIJ   201717    201719    2
```

and so on.. until the 52nd workweek starting from 201717.

How can I achieve this in SSIS?

I have tried the following options - Lookup,Merge Join,Union all.. but it joins with the first row only. I know Im very close but still missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is your end result (flat file, Excel file, sql table, etc)?  You could always load the Excel file into another staging table and then join the two tables using SQL.  That may help reduce the complexity since I know joining two sources with SSIS can sometimes be a pain.